# how to make call booking option with payment in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla3.0

We develop website in joomla 3.0 version.The client was asking call booking appoinment with payment.
In front end display one calender. once onhover the particular date it showing timing and place of the appoinment. Click that date redirect to another page and full details and payment button. like this any joomla free extension is there?

Comment: Have you searched the Joomla Extensions Directory: http://extensions.joomla.org ?

Comment: Check this link http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=appointment&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1